# Searching string while looping through $_SESSION variables

Tags: php

Is there a better way to search through $_SESSION variables (or any array) for a particular string than:

```
foreach($_SESSION as $k => $v){
    if(strstr($k, 'p_')){
```

Thanks.

edit: My keys will look similar to:

p_123
p_456
i_123
...

Comment: That depends: Do you have one or many 'p_' keys in the array?

Comment: I edited my question to answer your question, Truth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `$_SESSION` structure must stay "as is", IMO it is Ok.

However if all 'p_' elements could go under an array index like `$_SESSION['p'] = array('key1' => 'val1', ...)`, you could retrieve all 'p' elements at once.

BTW this is only micro optimization, go with the structure you're fine with.

**EDIT**: Just be careful with `strstr()`: if one day you must store keys like **i_123_p_456** into your `$_SESSION` array, you should switch to `if (strpos($k, 'p_') === 0)`.

Comment: my $_SESSION keys are all prefixed with 'p_' or some other character then an underscore.

Comment: Then your way is fine. @etm124 this is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: If you are fine with your current $_SESSION structure, I can't think of a better way than yours to access 'p_' elements.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding another answer as I'm taking a completely different approach.

If you're going to do this a lot, you could consider using filters.

```
function pprefix($var) {
  return(strstr($var, 'p_'));
}

$filtered = array_filter(array_keys($_SESSION), "pprefix");

foreach($fildered as $k) {
  echo("$k => " . $_SESSION[$k]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, Sergio, as I enjoy seeing other ways of doing things.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
if (array_key_exists('p_', $_SESSION)) {
  echo($_SESSION['p_']);
}
```

Or, if you only knows part of the name of the key (like the beggining), I'd use the array_keys() instead $k => $v, like so:

```
foreach(array_keys($_SESSION) as $k) {
  if(strstr($k, 'p_')){
    // do something.
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't do exactly the same thing, see http://www.php.net/strstr and http://www.php.net/array_key_exists

Comment: Not quite. the `strstr()` functions searches for a string inside of a string. He wants to match 'p_hello' or 'worldp_' as well, not just 'p_'.

Comment: Won't `array_key_exists` find the exact string (in this case, 'p_')? My $_SESSION variables look simiar to this: `$_SESSION['p_123']`.

Comment: No @etm124, it will only find `$_SESSION['_p'];` and that's it.